# Distance measure metric effect on K nearest neighbor curse of dimensionality?

Tags: machine-learning, weka, knn, text-classification

I understand Knn has a problem knows a "curse of dimensionality" when dealing with high dimension data and it justification is that it includes all features while calculating distance i.e. Euclidean distance where non important feature act as a noise and bias the results however i don't understand a few things

1) How cosine distance metric will be effected by this curse of dimensionality problem i.e. we define cosine distance as cosDistance =  1- cosSimilarity where cosSimilarity is favourable for high dimension data so how cosine distance may be effected by curse of dimensionality problem ?

2) Can we assign any weights to features in weka or can i apply feature selection locally to KNN ? Local to knn means i write my own class of K-NN where in classification i first convert training instance to lower dimension and then calculate test instance neighbors ?

Answer (score 2):

Cosine does not fundamentally differ from Euclidean distance.

In fact it is trivial to show that on normalized data with Euclidean length 1, Cosine and Euclidean distance *are* the same. In other words, Cosine is computing the Euclidean distance on L2 normalized vectors...

Thus, cosine is not more robust to the curse of dimensionality than Euclidean distance. However, cosine is popular with e.g. text data that has a high apparent dimensionality - often thousands of dimensions - but the *intrinsic* dimensionality must be much lower. Plus, it's mostly used for ranking; the actual distance value is ignored.